# Calculating paystring for loan data

Tags: c++, string, vector

**Example:**

Input: cpi = 100.0, payments = [100.0, 94.0, 90.0, 100.0, 200.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0 ]

Output: paystring = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Explanation: Since the first payment was 100.0 and that is greater than or equal to cpi - 5.0 (95.0) then the first element in the output is 0. Then the next element is 1 since 94.0 is less than cpi - 5.0 (95.0) i.e. missed a payment, then since the next element 90.0 is less than cpi - 5.0 (95.0) i.e. missed another payment than now we are at 2 (or 2 total missed payments). Then in the next element we had 100 then that counts as 1 payment made so now we made that payment that was due but we still didn't cover the other two payments from the prior month so we are still at 2. Then the process continues.

I have this so far:

```
double cpi = 100.0;
std::vector<double> payments = { 100.0, 94.0, 90.0, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0 };
std::vector<int> paystring(payments.size(), 0);

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < payments.size(); ++i) { 
    if (payments[i] <= cpi - 5.0) {
        paystring[i] = ++count;
    }

    else {
        paystring[i] = count;
    }
}

for (auto it : paystring)
    std::cout << it << " ";
```

Although, this is not correct since it fails to update count when I made lets say the full payment or more than the due amount (cpi). I just want to know what I need to change in my logic to make this work. Let me know if the example provided is unclear.

For example say I have

Input: cpi = 100.0, payments = [100.0, 94.0, 90.0, 100.0, 200.0, 100.0, 300.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0 ]

Output: [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

But I get

[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Here is a few more examples that are correct:

[image]

Comment: *it fails to update count when I made lets say the full payment or more than the due amount (cpi).* -- So you wrote the program, knowing what you wrote wouldn't satisfy all the requirements?  Or did you discover the issue just now and you want someone to debug the code for you?

Comment: *100.0 and that is less than or equal to cpi - 5.0 (95.0)* - please explain it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wrote the program initially to satisfy the first example, I then thought of another example to make it break. I am wondering what I need to (logic wise) to make sure I update count properly.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx -- Writing code and seeing there is an example where the code breaks -- hate to tell you, but this is one of the things you learn when you write programs -- redesign.  It isn't an anomaly to find out that initial designs are flawed in some way and then need to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a condition that if payment is too low, penalty is added, the customer is one month behind.

Add another condition: If over payment is made, for example $200, you want to give customer credit, that puts the customer one month ahead. Then add a condition that the customer is not ahead by a negative count.

```
std::vector<double> payments =  {
    100,  94, 90, 100, 200, 100, 300, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100
    //"0   1   1    0   -1    0   -2    0    0    0    0    0 <-penalty
    //"0   1   2    2    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0 <-penalty sum
};

double cpi = 100.0;
for(int i = 0; i < payments.size(); ++i)
{
    double payment = payments[i];
    if(payment <= (cpi - 5.0))
    {
        //one month behind on payment
        count++;
    }

    while((payment > cpi) && count)
    {
        //customer made large payment. 
        //allow count to decrease. 
        //but count cannot be less than zero
        count--;
        payment -= cpi;
    }

    paystring[i] = count;
}
```

Ouput for `100, 94, 90, 100, 200, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100`:

```
0 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 //expected output
0 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 //result
```

Ouput for `100,  94, 90, 100, 200, 100, 300, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100`:

```
0 1 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 //expected output
0 1 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 //result
```

My output is not the same, maybe the expected output is incorrect or you left something out. Note the 6th payment is 100, so there shouldn't be any change for that index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a condition that the payment just needs to be at least the cpi - 5.0, does your solution consider that? Also, for the balance  = payment - 100 can that just be generalized to balance = payment - cpi?

Comment: Yes it looks at `cpi - 5.0` I modify the code to make look more like yours. Notice the difference is that `count` can go down. As I said earlier, this doesn't exactly match your expected output, it doesn't work for the first data set either.

Comment: I believe your solutions works actually, is it okay to change the 100.0 to cpi?

Comment: Yes, I did that in the second edit. I removed the `100` from the calculation.